# Rewriting addition as a unary expression

Tags: c, compilation

I came across the following statement:

> A smart compiler can recognize that `x = x + 1` can be treated the same as `++x`.

Why is the prefix-operator used here instead of the post-fix operator (or either, if it doesn't matter)? For example, if I had the following loop:

```
while (x < 10) {
    ...
    x++; // wouldn't this be the same as doing ++x here?
}
```

What would be a case that shows how `x = x + 1` is equivalent to `++x` and not `x++` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example. Suppose you have something like this:

```
a = (x = x + 1);
```

This would be equivalent to

```
a = ++x;
```

but *not* to

```
a = x++;
```

Answer (score 3):

> What would be a case that shows how x = x + 1 is equivalent to ++x and not x++ ?

Any case where the value of the expression is used.

One example: `if((x = x + 1) < 10)` is equivalent to `if(++x < 10)` but not `if(x++ < 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if you use `++i` or `i++` as a standalone expression. The only difference is the value of the expression, which is unused in both cases.

You could also write `i += 1` or `i = i + 1` and the compiler should generate the same code for all 4 variations (with optimisations enabled).

If the value of the expression is used, `i = i + 1` and `i += 1` are equivalent to `++i` and all have the updated value, whereas `i++` has the original value of `i`.

Comment: "Unused in both cases" or "not used in either case" would be better. The wording "not used in both cases" suggests that it is or at least may be used in one of the cases.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: thank you, indeed there was a third possible interpretation, which was unintended :)

Answer (score 0):

The expression `i++` returns the value of `i` before incrementing it, while the expression `++i` returns the value of `i` after incrementing.

For example:

```
int i = 1;
int j = i++; // j now equals 1, i equal 2
```

And `++i`

```
int i = 1;
int j = ++i; // j and i both equal 2.
```

The expression `x = x + 1` returns the value of `x` after incrementing, not before it, so it is equivalent to `++i`